# Неопределенное количество логических условий в цикле

Tags: python, циклы, логические-выражения

Написал небольшой фрагмент с циклом while.

```
user_input = None

while not (user_input == '1' or user_input == '2'):

    user_input = input("PLZ choose what you want to do\n create=1\n update=2\n")

    print(user_input)
```

Есть ли какая-то возможность переделать этот фрагмент в более абстрактную функцию, с неопределенным количеством OR условий, которые будут передаваться как аргументы в функцию, не могу придумать как это реализовать. Изменяемую строку в inpute я создам через цикл for это понятно.

что-то типа:

```
while not (user_input == '1' or user_input == '2' or user_input == N):
```

Как я вижу, эти проверки нужно выносить в другой цикл, а в цикле while создавать одну проверку как результат проверок всех остальных условий в другом цикле в теле этого цикла. Но может есть какой-то другой вариант более правильный?

Comment: А оператор `in`? Он тут напрашивается `user_input in possible_values`, где `possible_values = ['1', '2', ...]`?

Comment: Да, именно то. что нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

может так?

```
while user_input not in ['1', '2']:
```

Comment: Да. то что нужно!